# find text for non-ASCII characters in python

Tags: python, ascii

Is there any way to search text between parentheses for non-ascii caracters in python?
I use:

```
text=line.strip()[1:-1]
```

but I get the error:

> "Non-ASCII character '\xe2' "

Comment: Is the string in Unicode? If so, which encoding is used? Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? You should show us which value of `line` gives you this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out non-printable characters using [string.printable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable). Example:

```
>>>import string
>>>something = "(abcd\xe2)"
>>>printable = set(string.printable)
>>>print (''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, something)))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using utf, first line of your file should be: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`